# CallStatus URL is not being called

Tags: twilio-php

I am using the following code to initiate calls. If the call is not answered, I want to capture this event (unanswered call) and call an alternative phone number. Currently with the below code, if a phone is not answered once, it is calling 3 times and then giving up without calling the StatusCallback URL at all. What am I doing wrong? (I can call the URL from browser with parameters.)

Thx a lot.

// Piece of PHP code making the call
        $this->info('Calling providers:');

```
    $account_sid = ...
    $auth_token = ...
    $client = new \Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token);
    try {
        $this->info ('Calling phone... ');
            // Make a call
            $call = $client->account->calls->create('+448008021203', '+'.$phone_to_call, 'http://xyz/order_msg.html', array(
                'Method' => 'GET',
                "StatusCallback" => "http://xyz/phone_events?alt_phone=".$alternate_phone,
                "StatusCallbackMethod" => "GET",
                "StatusCallbackEvent" => array("completed"),
                'Record' => 'false',
            ));
            $this->info('Called with :' . $call);
        }

    }catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->error('Exception :'.$e->getMessage());
    }
```

// StatusCallback URL = http://xyz/phone_events PHP-Laravel code

```
    $status =Input::get('CallStatus');
    $alternate_phone =Input::get('alt_phone');

    if (! empty($alternate_phone) && ! empty($status)) {

        if ($status != "completed" || $status != "queued") {
            /* start the next call */
            $account_sid = ...;
            $auth_token = ...;
            $client = new \Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token);

            try {

                $client->account->calls->create('+448008021203', '+'.$alt_phone, 'http://xyz/order_msg.html', array(
                    'Method' => 'GET',
                    "StatusCallback" => "http://xyz/phone_events,
                    "StatusCallbackMethod" => "GET",
                    "StatusCallbackEvent" => array("completed"),
                    'Record' => 'false',
                ));

            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $log->error('Phone Events Error: ' . $e);
            }
        }
    }
```